# Android Studio Java pop an Activity from Backstack based on a condition in next activity

Tags: java, android, back-stack

I have a case where I need to pop an activity from backstack based on a condition in the next activity. Say there are 3 activities A, B & C.

Activity A has a list and when user taps on a specific item activity B starts with a form that has many items. User fills the form(partial or complete) and can preview the same in activity C. Inside activity C he can confirm the details or simply go back to activity B and continue working on the form. What I want is activity B popped out of backstack if user taps "confirm" in activity C and pressing back button should take user to activity A instead of B.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start Activity C for result https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result from Activity B

And then in situation when you want go back from C-> A you have to

- return information from Activity C (check that link above for more information how to do that)
- receive this info in B and
- add **finish()** in Activity B where you received that specific data returned by activity C

Answer (score 3):

You should try to use the `fragment.addToBackStack(null)` method for the activity
`B`. You'll need to convert it to a `FragmentActivity` though.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot do this for 2 reasons. One, there is no way I can convert the activity B to a fragment for practical reasons (too long to explain here), and Two, I need to remove it from the backstack only based on the condition in activity C, so when activity B loads or even when activity C starts, I would not know if activity B needs to be removed from the backstack. It's only when user confirms inside activity C, I want B to be removed from backstack